¿Cuál es el tamaño de una pila de tareas en linux y en windows (sistemas operativos)?
Haciendo una investigación me gustaría saber el tamaño de la pila de tareas en los sistemas operativos de Linux y Windows. Logré recuperar información de que en Linux es de 4MB y en Windows es de 1 MB, pero lo encontré de fuentes poco confiables.

La única respuesta confiable la obtendrás mirando el fuente del S.O. El valor que extraiga depende de la versión de S.O. y otras opciones que hayas fijado durante la compilación.

En realidad no hay un tamaño fijo. Se puede cambiar en las opciones del compilador. Si hay un tamaño por defecto definido por el compilador. Por ejemplo https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=msvc-170
